# Do i need to apply Boolean before animating it

Tags: modeling, animation, modifiers, rigging

So I'm very new at rigging and animating,
i made a model with alot of booleans. now i want to rig and animate it,
i'm confused wether i need to apply the boolean and make every changes destructive or rig and animate WITH the boolean parented to the object

sorry im very new in this category

Comment: I would say yes, apply the boolean, what kind of object is it?

Comment: its a hard surface object with alot of boolean decals to add detail and some cut out to make the model more interesting

Comment: the question would rather be: do you have any good reason to keep the boolean?

Comment: yes, the client might want to change it later, this is the first iteration of the object

Comment: in that case keep the boolean, does it cause problems for the rigging?

Comment: thats what i dont know, i tried but it makes the viewport really heavy on solid mode playback

Comment: I think you should keep a copy of the non-destructive version, duplicate, apply the modifiers, parent to armature, etc... but maybe show some screenshots, show the wireframe, etc...

Answer (score 0):

If you parent the Boolean objects to their respective bones on the mesh, you might be able to get away with keeping the modifiers active. Otherwise, you'd be better off just applying them.